# Find MIN value based on two columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, min

I've table in MySQL with athletic performs.

**Structure:**

```
id (PRIMARY KEY)    
athlete_id (FOREIGN KEY)    
perform     
category_id     
discipline_id
```

If I want to select the best performs from this table (each athlete can be in results max once), I use this query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  performs NATURAL 
  JOIN athletes 
  JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      athlete_id,
      MIN(perform) AS perform,
      category_id,
      discipline_id 
    FROM
      zaznamy 
    WHERE discipline_id = 4 
      AND category_id = 3 
    GROUP BY athlete_id) rec 
    ON performs.athlete_id = rec.athlete_id 
    AND performs.perform = rec.perform 
    AND performs.category_id = rec.category_id 
    AND performs.discipline_id = rec.discipline_id 
ORDER BY performs.perform 
LIMIT 25
```

I get right results. But I want to select the best performs from one discipline and more category together (e.g. Mens with Juniors etc). How do I use clause GROUP BY for two columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand something, but you can add two columns in group by, like the following example. Just add ,(comma) between the two or more columns.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM
  performs NATURAL 
  JOIN athletes 
  JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      athlete_id,
      MIN(perform) AS perform,
      category_id,
      discipline_id 
    FROM
      zaznamy 
    WHERE discipline_id = 4 
    GROUP BY athlete_id,category_id) rec 
    ON performs.athlete_id = rec.athlete_id 
    AND performs.perform = rec.perform 
    AND performs.category_id = rec.category_id 
    AND performs.discipline_id = rec.discipline_id 
ORDER BY performs.perform 
LIMIT 25 enter code here
```

**EDIT - UPDATE**

Ok, now I understand your problem. This is quite common, actually, where you want first to find the max value of a group and then request additional info on that value.

One way to achieve this is with a nested query as follow

```
SELECT ss.athlete_id,ss.perform,category_id
FROM performs ss
inner join
(SELECT
    athlete_id, MIN(perform) AS perform
FROM 
    performs
WHERE
    discipline_id = 4 AND category_id IN (1,3,5,7,9) 
GROUP BY
    athlete_id) tt
    on tt.athlete_id = ss.athlete_id and ss.perform = tt.perform
```

The result is the one you described above.

Comment: Thanks, I´ve tried this update, but your query select the best perform from each category for each athlete. But I want to select the best perform of athlete throw all categories (his Personal Best).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand exactly what you are trying. If you want his Personal best then your query is correct. Could you provide with an example of what your output should look like, given the data?

Comment: And one more thing please :)
If in results will be one athlete twice (athlete has two same performs in two different categories), how do I edit the SQL query for having just one perform?

Comment: The way this query is written, an athlete can only appear once (because of the group by clause in the nested query). So no athlete can appear twice. :)

Comment: Unfortunately yes, Please check the result below.

Comment: What do you want to output in this case? I don't understand exactly the issue. You wish to display only for one athlete his best perform in a category?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If I want to choose the best perform for the athlete, I think THE ONE, but function MIN(....) return more values, if athlete has more same best perform. I´ve tried DISTINCT, but the result were same.

Comment: Then you just have to add an additional `select` statement above all and `group by` the category id, with `min(perform)` in the `select` :)

Answer (score 0):

If I use this query:

```
SELECT
    athlete_id, MIN(perform) AS perform, category_id 
FROM 
    performs
WHERE
    discipline_id = 4 AND category_id IN (1,3,5,7,9) 
GROUP BY
    athlete_id, category_id
```

I get this results:

```
athlete_id perform category_id
1          11,14      1
1          11,54      3
1          11,54      5
1          10,71      7
2          11,04      1
2          11,24      3
2          11,54      5
2          12,14      7
3          10,94      1
4          10,94      1
4          11,34      3
```

But I need this result:

```
athlete_id perform category_id
1          10,71      7
2          11,04      1
3          10,94      1
4          10,94      1
```

For each athlete_id the best perform at once category_id.
This result will be JOIN with full table "perform".

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```
SELECT ss.athlete_id,ss.perform,category_id
FROM performs ss
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
 athlete_id, MIN(perform) AS perform
FROM 
 performs
WHERE
 discipline_id = 4 AND category_id IN (1,3,5,7,9) 
GROUP BY
 athlete_id) tt
ON tt.athlete_id = ss.athlete_id and ss.perform = tt.perform
```

Results:

```
athlete_id    perform    category_id
1             7,04       1
2             7,14       1
3             7,14       1
4             7,24       1
5             7,14       1
6             7,24       1
6             7,24       3
7             7,02       1
8             7,07       1
9             7,34       1
10            7,34       1
11            7,18       1
12            7,04       3
13            7,44       1
13            7,44       5
14            7,44       1
15            7,27       1
```

I´ve tried clause DISTINCT but results were same.